# odoo mod_wsgi lxml.etree undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1

Tags: python, odoo

I try to configure mod_wsgi to access odoo thanks my domain name.
I followed [this tutorial](https://opensourceholic.com/2014/05/30/how-to-deploy-odoo-openerp-8-with-mod_wsgi-on-ubuntu-linux-servers-vps-ec2/).

But when I go to my site I get this error :

```
[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89] mod_wsgi (pid=30445): Target WSGI script '/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp-wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89] mod_wsgi (pid=30445): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp-wsgi.py'.

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89] Traceback (most recent call last):

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp-wsgi.py", line 15, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     import openerp

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp/__init__.py", line 58, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     import modules

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp/modules/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     from . import db, graph, loading, migration, module, registry

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp/modules/graph.py", line 13, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     import openerp.osv as osv

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp/osv/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     import osv

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 4, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     from ..exceptions import except_orm

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]   File "/opt/odoo-v9-prod/openerp/exceptions.py", line 15, in <module>

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89]     from lxml import etree

[Thu Nov 03 16:00:57 2016] [error] [client 176.189.147.89] ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7.9/lib/python2.7/site-packages/lxml/etree.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS2_DecodeLatin1
```

I test my python encodage and it is UCS2.
I reinstalled `lxml`.

Answer (score 0):

Your mod_wsgi is compiled for a different Python installation than the Python virtual environment you are trying to force it to use, or the Python shared library it is finding. Worse is that what ever it is using was compiled with different width for Unicode character support. You need to uninstall mod_wsgi and reinstall mod_wsgi from source code and compile it against the specific Python version you do want to use, forcing it to use the correct shared library if necessary. You may also want to consider reinstalling your custom Python version to use a configuration which aligns with what is generally regarded as best practice for the platform. Linux system usually use 4 byte Unicode, not 2.

Some stuff for you to read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/checking-your-installation.html#python-shared-library
- http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2015/06/installing-custom-python-version-into.html

Ignore the fact that the latter talks about Docker, all still relevant to normal Python install as well.